# Closing ContextMenu with Templated MenuItems

Tags: wpf, xaml, contextmenu, controltemplate

I have created a customized Context menu where I changed the appearance of all items.
These Items contain different controls like comboboxes and buttons. Now I want the menu to close if a button was pressed or a combobox item was selected. Currently the menu just remains open.
Can you give me a hint?

This is a simplified code to show what I did:

```
<ContextMenu StaysOpen="False">
    <MenuItem>
        <MenuItem.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid MinWidth="200">
                    <Button Command="{Binding SomeWorkingCommandBinding}">OK</Button>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </MenuItem.Template>
    </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

As mentioned, I would like to close the menu when I hit that OK button.

**UPDATE**

The following button (or any other control) does the trick without the need of Blend SDK:

```
<Button.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ContextMenu.IsOpen)" Storyboard.Target="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <sys:Boolean>False</sys:Boolean>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Button.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `ChangePropertyAction` which is part of the [Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10801) to change the `IsOpen` property of the ContextMenu as soon as the Button is clicked:

```
<ContextMenu x:Name="MyContextMenu">
  <MenuItem>
    <MenuItem.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid MinWidth="200">
                <Button Command="{Binding SomeWorkingCommandBinding}" Content="OK">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                            <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" PropertyName="IsOpen" Value="False"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </MenuItem.Template>
  </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

You'll need the following namespaces:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"                  
xmlns:ei="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"
```

Comment: I like the Idea, however your sample is not working since the TargetObject cannot be an ElementName outside the ControlTemplate, so I used a RelativeSource for that. However I added a solution without Blend to my initial Post.

Comment: Correct - Updated answer with RelativeSource (for future references...)