# ContextMenu for ListViewItem only

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, listviewitem

I have a context menu - problem is I need it to only open when a listviewitem is clicked.  Right now it will open if I click anywhere in the listview or in the header.

```
<ListView> 
    <ListView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="More Info" Command="{Binding MoreInfo}" />
        </ContextMenu>
     </ListView.ContextMenu>
     <ListView.View> 
         <GridView> 
           <!-- columns and stuff here -->
         </GridView>
     </ListView.View>
 </ListView>
```

I have tried adding the ContextMenu as a resource and applying it as a style, but this breaks the command (clicking on More Info should open a dialog window, doesnt work this way)

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ItemContextMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="More Info" Command="{Binding MoreInfo}" Background="WhiteSmoke" />
    </ContextMenu>
</ListView.Resources>
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" >
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ItemContextMenu}" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

So not sure how to restrict the context menu to only the listviewitem and have the command work.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use the [RelativeSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource.aspx) in the command binding in the template, and it will work:

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ItemContextMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="More Info" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.MoreInfo, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}" Background="WhiteSmoke" />
    </ContextMenu>
</ListView.Resources>

<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" >
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ItemContextMenu}" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  Any change you could explain exactly what this is doing? I'm a little fuzzy on what FindAncestor does.

Comment: In your case, the RelativeSource trying to find the first ListView control in UI tree and use it as binding source. Therefore, we must write `DataContext` and then property name.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on this very helpful post...If your `ContextMenu` has custom buttons or other objects within a `ControlTemplate`, I have combined the answer above with the answer from  [Closing ContextMenu with Templated MenuItems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007838/closing-contextmenu-with-templated-menuitems) so that when a user clicks on the `Button`, the `ContextMenu` closes normally only using XAML.  This took about 10 hours to put together.  Hope it saves you time.  Supports MVVM `ICommand` usage.  I also used the `Style` for the `ContextMenu` from [this post][2] to elminate the 90's look.

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ItemContextMenu" Style="{StaticResource HorizontalContextMenu}">
        <MenuItem>
            <MenuItem.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid MinHeight="50" MinWidth="50">
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource CloseAppButton}" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.DeleteCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}" >
                            <Button.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ContextMenu.IsOpen)" Storyboard.Target="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <sys:Boolean>False</sys:Boolean>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger>
                            </Button.Triggers>
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </MenuItem.Template>
        </MenuItem>

        <MenuItem>
            <MenuItem.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid MinHeight="50" MinWidth="50">
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource AddButton}" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.TestCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}" >
                            <Button.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ContextMenu.IsOpen)" Storyboard.Target="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <sys:Boolean>False</sys:Boolean>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger>
                            </Button.Triggers>
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </MenuItem.Template>
        </MenuItem>

        <MenuItem>
            <MenuItem.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid MinHeight="50" MinWidth="50">
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource PluginInfoButton}" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.TestCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}" >
                            <Button.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ContextMenu.IsOpen)" Storyboard.Target="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <sys:Boolean>False</sys:Boolean>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger>
                            </Button.Triggers>
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </MenuItem.Template>
        </MenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>

</ListView.Resources>
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" >
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ItemContextMenu}" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```