# Context menu event or trigger of a control inside an itemtemplate of a listview is not fired

Tags: c#, wpf, itemtemplate, eventtrigger

I've got following problem. Following situation in my xaml code:

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListViewItems}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <WrapPanel>
                    <Label Content="Test">
                        <Label.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">

                            </ContextMenu>
                        </Label.ContextMenu>
                    </Label>
                </WrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseUp">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LabelMouseUpCommand}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </ListView>
```

After clicking a label no context menu is shown and the trigger does not work as well, LabelMouseUpCommand method is not entered. I fear the listview handles the click itself and does not pass it to the embedded controls.

Is there any way to pass it to the controls. In future i want to add several controls to the itemtemplate and everyone has it own different context menu.

Comment: If you right click the label can you see the context menu?

Comment: `Label.Background` is null, this required you to click exactly on the text to have menu popped up. Set background to `White` (or `Transparent`).

Comment: @Mattia Magosso: No, no context menu is shown after right click.

Comment: @Sinatr: Changing the background does not help, no context menu is shown and the trigger does not work.

Comment: Perhaps menu is only possible for `ListViewItem`, then you have to add it via `ItemContainerStyle`, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18921462/1997232). Regarding command, you define it for `ListView` and not for `Label`.

Comment: Have you tried changing your event trigger to `RoutedEvent="ListViewItem.PreviewMouseUp"`?

Comment: I tried to setup an application with the code you wrote and it works fine, probably the error is in some template you're using

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for my problem with this [stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25021052/1340804)

There the author explains that the contextmenu does not lie in the same visual tree as the listview. Therefore my initial binding can't work because the source can't be found within the visual tree.

Furthermore Sinatr was totally right, the trigger was initially defined for listview, not for the label.

Here is my working code:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListViewItems}" x:Name="listViewMain">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel>
                <Label Content="Test">
                    <Label.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.MenuItems, Source={x:Reference listViewMain}}">

                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Label.ContextMenu>
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseUp">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.LabelMouseUpCommand, Source={x:Reference listViewMain}}" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </Label>
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```