# RelativeSource For Context Menu stops DataTrigger working

Tags: wpf, listview, contextmenu

First Time poster long time reader and new to wpf so please be gentle with me :-)

I am trying to create a list of users with a ListView, I am grouping in a CollectionView with the offline users in red. With a context menu that only shows when clicking on users name.

For code for the contextmenu I got from another post here [ContextMenu for ListViewItem only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921188/contextmenu-for-listviewitem-only)

My issue is that as soon as I add the context menu, the color change no longer triggers, 
so I believe I am mixing the methods without understanding how they are working.

```
<Grid>
             <ListView x:Name="lvUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding items}">
                <ListView.View>
                 <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn> 
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"/>
                                 <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="{Binding UserName}"/>

                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
                 </ListView.View>

            <ListView.Resources>
               <ContextMenu x:Key="ItemContextMenu">
               <MenuItem Header="More Info" Click="MenuItemDelete_Click" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.MoreInfo, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}" Background="WhiteSmoke" />
                </ContextMenu>

                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value = "Red"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value ="Online">
                         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>

            </ListView.Resources>

            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" >
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ItemContextMenu}" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14"  Foreground="Black"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>

            </ListView>
        </Grid>
```

[what it should look like][1]

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yu0Rx.png

```
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<User> items = new List<User>();

            items.Add(new User() { Icon = ".\images\\white.png", UserName = "Tim Black", MessageColor ="Black", Status = Status.Online });
            items.Add(new User() { Icon = ".\white.png", UserName = "Colin Black", MessageColor = "Black", Status = Status.Online });
            items.Add(new User() { Icon = ".\images\\white.png", UserName = "Fred in Red", MessageColor = "Red" , Status = Status.Offline });

            lvUsers.ItemsSource = items;

            CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lvUsers.ItemsSource);
            PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("Status");
            view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);

        }

        private void MenuItemDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("context Pressed as source" + e.Source.ToString());
        }
    }
    public enum Status { Online, Offline };

    public class User
    {
        public string Icon { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string MessageColor { get; set; }
        public Status Status { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Have you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged? Also i see there is an issue the x:Name. I guess it should be lvUser. Can you show please the code behind

Comment: @Julian I added the rest of the code behind, no INotifyPropertyChanged, what would be the issue with X:name ?

Comment: please update you XAML, the ListView it self is missing

Comment: please note, you offline and online is swapped. maybe you want try an converter and remove the Messagecolor. just convert online and offline to your color.

Comment: Please try the updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working.

Add a new class to your project `StatusToForeGroundConverter`.

```
public class StatusToForeGroundConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(value is Status status)
        {
            return status == Status.Online ? "black" : "red";
        }

        //fallback
        return "black";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Add the converter to your XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:StatusToForeGroundConverter x:Key="StatusConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then just bind to it like:

```
<TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="{Binding UserName}" Foreground="{Binding Status,Converter={StaticResource StatusConverter}}"/>
```

Full xaml:

```
<Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="lvUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding items}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="{Binding UserName}" Foreground="{Binding Status,Converter={StaticResource StatusConverter}}"/>

                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>

            <ListView.Resources>
                <ContextMenu x:Key="ItemContextMenu">
                    <MenuItem Header="More Info" Click="MenuItemDelete_Click" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.MoreInfo, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}" Background="WhiteSmoke" />
                </ContextMenu>

            </ListView.Resources>

            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" >
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding MessageColor}" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14"  Foreground="Black"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>

        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you @Julian I can see from you code that I can use the MessageColor binding to set the color, however this still does not resolve the issue with the trigger, as that was what I was using to set a default color of black, and red for online using the Status enum in the List<User>, if you follow the "what it will look like" link to a image, your see what I was aiming for in appearance

Comment: Okay, for that would recommend a converter. Give me some mins and I will type you one. I don't have a PC right now.

Comment: Thank you for all your help just what I needed, I learned much today :-)

Comment: It's a pleasure, have a nice day