# Binding cannot find source when trying to access the datacontext of a custom listview contextmenu

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I got a very similar problem with [ContextMenu for ListViewItem only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921188/contextmenu-for-listviewitem-only) but the solution doesn't seem to work in my case.

```
<GroupBox Header="PlayOffs" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ListView Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding PlayoffSeries}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SeriesTemplate}">
                <ListView.Resources>
                   <ContextMenu x:Key="cm">
                       <MenuItem Header="SetLive" Click="SetSeriesLive"/>
                       <MenuItem Header="Start" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=DataContext.CanStart, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}" Click="StartSeries"/>
                   </ContextMenu>
                </ListView.Resources>
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource cm}"/>
                        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="HandleDoubleClick" />
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListView>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>
</GroupBox>
```

I get an error for the `IsEnabled` binding of the MenuItem `Start` saying `Cannot find source:RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ListView',AncestorLevel='1'`

The click command works like a charm, essentially what I want to do is to bind the IsEnabled property of the menuitem to the `CanStart` property of the underlying datacontext provided from the listviewItem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a dumdum. I just tried with `AncestorType=ContextMenu` and it seems to be working like a charm. Still not entirely sure why the first solution worked for the other question though. I suppose its related to the datamodel bound to the listview.

Comment: The ContextMenu is not part of the list view's visual tree. That's why using RelativeSource inside the ContextMenu can't find a ListView. The ContextMenu generally shares the same DataContext as the owing control. That's why your solution works.